# How to reliably list and drop all spatial indexes in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-spatial

In my open-source database migration project [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway), I have a feature that cleans all objects in the current database schema, without dropping the schema itself.

The typical implementation works as follows:

- List all objects
- Generate drop statements for these objects

**Oracle Spatial Indexes** have been causing me a lot of grief though.

How can I **reliably enumerate** them in order to produce DROP INDEX xyz statements?

Note: This must work on both **XE, 10g and 11g**. All references in the MDSYS schema must be gone.

My current solution looks like this:

On XE:

- DELETE FROM mdsys.user_sdo_geom_metadata
- DELETE FROM mdsys.sdo_index_metadata_table WHERE sdo_index_owner = USER
- SELECT object_type, object_name FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'TABLE'
- DROP *table_name* CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE /* for all tables */

On Oracle 10g:

- DELETE FROM mdsys.user_sdo_geom_metadata
- SELECT object_type, object_name FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' and object_name not like 'MDRT_%$'
- DROP *table_name* CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE /* for all tables */

10g seems to cascade the removal of the metadata in MDSYS.sdo_index_metadata_table and the removal of the spatial index tables (MDRT_1234$ and the like).

XE doesn't.

Both 10g and XE don't cascade the removal of the metadata in MDSYS.user_sdo_geom_metadata

Comment: how are you searching for them at the moment?

Comment: I've expanded my question to include my current solution (which unfortunately is a big hack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by enumerating all SPATIAL indexes using

```
select INDEX_NAME from USER_SDO_INDEX_INFO
```

And using INDEX_NAME to generate DROP statements like

```
DROP INDEX my_index
```

Answer (score 0):

on 10g, try the [xxx_SDO_INDEX_yyy](http://stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10826/sdo_objrelschema.htm#i1003951) views or alternatively look for objects with type `SPATIAL_INDEX`. You could drop each of these first then drop the table. I don't know whether these exist on XE or not.

Comment: The indexes are not marked as SPATIAL_INDEX. They have an object_type of INDEX, just like all others.